# javascript multidimensional array creation and insertion

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I want to create an array in javascript

```
var sortValues = array(
                 2 => array(3,4,5),
                 3 => array(5,6,7), 
                 12 => array (7,4,5) 
                 );
```

Now I am looping through all textboxes of my form. Every textbox has id like `2_3` means 2 will be the main index of the array.

**My html markup looks like**

```
<input type="text" value="3" id="2_5" name="2_5">
<input type="text" value="4" id="2_5" name="2_6">
<input type="text" value="5" id="2_5" name="2_7">
<input type="text" value="5" id="3_1" name="3_1">
<input type="text" value="6" id="3_2" name="3_2">
..................................
```

Now I want to check if 2 exists in array `sortValues`, I will take the value of the text box and and will check if this value exists in the array against 2 then I will put an alert that value already exists, if value doesn't exists push the value in sub array. Means I need to put 3 against 2 I will check if 3 exists against 2, if yes put alert else push in array.

If 2 (main index) doens't exist create a new index in array and so on. I have tried so far

```
var sortvalues = new Array();
$(":text").each(function () {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        ids = id.split("_");
        parent = ids[0];
        child = ids[1];
        if(typeof sortvalues[parent] !== 'undefined') {
            if(typeof sortvalues[parent][$(this).val()] !== 'undefined') {
                alert("Value already exists");
            } else {
                sortvalues[parent][] = $(this).val();
            }
        } else {
            sortvalues.push(parent);
        }
    }
});
console.log(sortValues);
```

Which gives `["2", "2", "2"]` which is wrong. Can Any body guide me how can I achieve above mentioned array in above mentioned criteria ??/

Comment: what is your html markup, can you create fiddle ?

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript and PHP, `sortvalues[parent][] = $(this).val()` is not right. Also your top array declaration is not valid JS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to create an array in another array?

For example :

```
var sortValues = new Array();
sortValues[2] = Array(3,4,5);
```

Please clarify your question. And the following:

```
sortvalues[parent][] = $(this).val()  --> you can't leave empty for the second array.
```